# Convert 0x750201 to human readable date

Tags: javascript, php, date

So the date I have is `0x750201` which should include the year, month and day.

I've got the Javascript code that converts this to a date:

```
function getYMD(n) {
  // [y,m,d]
  return [(((n >> 16) & 0xFF) + 1900), ((n >>> 8) & 0xFF), (n & 0xFF)];
}
```

But I have no idea what it's doing and thus can't translate it to php, any ideas?

Here are some examples of what the code translate into:

```
0x750201 is 2017, 2, 1
0x75020e is 2017, 2, 14
```

Comment: 0x stands for hexa. The date is stored as  hexa numbers, and is using those as bits. & and >> are bits level operators. I would guess its the number of seconds from default date stored as hexa numbers, maybe?

Comment: which part confuses you? the only stumbling block is that PHP doesn't have `>>>` but changing that to `>>` will produce the same result anyway

Comment: Why would that format be preferred over say 20170301? Just curious.

Comment: @RobG by that format, do you mean 0x750201? Then I would love to have 20170301 but unfortunately, the dates are coming from someplace out of my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh hah, thanks @Jaromanda X, didn't realise you could do this in PHP.

Turns out this does indeed work just fine, thanks for the help!

```
function getYMD($n) {
  // [y,m,d]
  return [((($n >> 16) & 0xFF) + 1900), (($n >> 8) & 0xFF), ($n & 0xFF)];
}
print_r(getYMD(0x750201));
```